# Is there a way to cover Twitter's iframe?

Tags: html, api, twitter, hyperlink

We are building a sharing tool on our site and want to skin over the standard Twitter Share button.  But we're having issues.  Any idea how to skin it over?

Comment: How about making your own button that has the same link? lol

Answer (score 0):

Actually this link will help you > https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

To skin over the standard Twitter share button you would refer to the following example

> Build Your Own Tweet Button
>
> We allow you to build your own Tweet Button too. In this example we'll
>   take the share link and add a border and icon using CSS. Note in this
>   example when the Tweet Button is clicked the Share Box will open in a
>   new window or tab (depending on the browser). In practice though, you
>   will likely want to include a javascript handler to open the Share Box
>   in a popup window instead.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #custom-tweet-button a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 20px;
    background: url('http://a4.twimg.com/images/favicon.ico') 1px center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>

<div id="custom-tweet-button">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
</div>
```